# How to manually reference figure so that fonts are consistent

Tags: fonts, floats, citing, subfloats, labels

I have a pdf figure that includes subplots (e.g. a,b,c, etc) but these subplots are not part of latex, they are in the actual pdf.

I have actual latex subplots later in my paper.  When I reference the actual latex subplots I'll get references that look like "1a", "1b", "3c", etc.

When I reference my plot that contains a subplot in the pdf, not in latex, I'll get references like "1", "2", etc.  If I manually add the letters of the subplot I'm interested in I can make the reference correct, but the fonts are different between my manual reference and latex's version.

How can I manually reference my pdf with subplots inside so that the fonts are the same across my manual references and latex's references without changing my template file?

Edit:

I am using Figure \ref{fig:myLatexSubfig} for the latex subfigure and \ref{fig:myManualSubfig}a (for example) for my manual subfigure.

Edit2:

Im using the ACM conference format template given [here](https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template).  I believe that Times New Roman is used as the font for ACM but I have no idea what font is used for the figures.  At this point, I'm interested primarily in knowing how to change the fonts of the reference on a per case basis more than I am in getting the correct font (Once I know how to change it I can figure it out on my own; though a full solution would be wonderful).

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a TeX code that shows what you are doing. And I'm also wondering why you do not decompose the pdf into the subfigures, and include them in subfigures. This may save you from a lot of trouble.

Comment: @marmot See my edit.  Also I agree that it would be easier to do that, however, hindsight is 20/20.  Given the amount of time I have available and the effort needed to redo it I'm stuck with taking a less than ideal approach.  If there is no easy way to fix it I will just ignore the font differences and go forward as it is, but I would prefer to get it correct if possible.

Comment: maybe have a look at `\phantomsubcaption` from the subcaption package

Comment: If you would add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) maybe we could tell you how to manually imitate the fonts.

Comment: Are you at liberty to share the image with the subfigures? It might be easy to split it in several individual figures.

Comment: @samcart No I can't.  My edit contains the closest I can get to a MWE (unless you're looking for a full latex write up that will actually run).  Essentially my problem is that "a" in my example when I use \ref{fig:myLatexSubfig} will have a different font than the "a" when I use \ref{fig:myManualSubfig}a

Comment: Please have a look at the link how to make a MWE. Without a short compilable document, how shall we see the difference between `\ref{fig:myManualSubfig}a` and `\ref{fig:myLatexSubfig}`? It does neither contain the packages you are using, nor a subfigure.

Comment: You write, "the fonts are different between my manual reference and latex's version." Are you at liberty to divulge with fonts, or are least which font shapes, are involved? E.g., do the subplots feature numbers 2a, 2b, etc in a sans-serif font? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico see my edit.  The actual fonts in the subplot don't matter, I'm not using those.  The issue is the actual reference in the text. I'm using ACM conference format and using the standard "label{}" and "ref{}" tag to reference figures.  Because I have manually created the subplots and placed everything in a single figure I have to manually add which subplot I'm referring to when I cite the plot.  When I do this the font of the manual addition doesn't match what would otherwise be manually generated.

Comment: @HXSP1947 - I'm really regret to have to say this, but your preceding comment is completely impenetrable. So sorry to have tried to help -- I probably just wasted your time.

Comment: *friendly* on this site, MWEs are usually expected, so that the magicians can take it, play around with and get back to you with a solution. The more you boil down your problem to a minimal example, that still accurately represents what you want to achieve in your document, the better the answers will be. The art is in reducing to a few lines of code without removing what is essential to your problem. THIS WILL save you a lot of time (and give the community the opportunity to be helpful, at all). Note: We're all doing this for free.

Comment: In your case, consider making a new pdf with two dummy subfigures with captions in whatever wrong font. Then use that instead of your real document, which you seem to not be allowed to publish. Then produce an MWE with that dummy pdf. Heck, I don't know, it's all a black box to me (hint).

Comment: An MWE *is* "a full latex write up that will actually run". If the images themselves are irrelevant, as you say, then you can even leave them out of the example altogether, just have two figures with captions and cross references. Take a copy of your document, and remove all the text except for a figure or two, and two different cross-references. (Check that fonts are inconsistent.) Then remove as much as you can from the preamble, all the time making sure that the problem doesn't go away. Continue until you've reached the smallest code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for the ready to use MWE in your question. Without having to create a new document from scratch it was really easy as cake to answer your question!

---

From the documentation of the class you use:

> The package subcaption [8] is recommended for complex figures with several subplots or subfigures that require separate subcaptioning.

This package allows you to "fake" the different parts of the image.

```
\documentclass{acmart}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  {
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \phantomsubcaption\label{cat}
    \phantomsubcaption\label{dog}
  }
  \caption{Two animals: \subref{cat} a huge cat,
           and \subref{dog} an elephant}
  \label{animals}
\end{figure}

\ref{cat} 

\ref{dog}

\ref{animals}

\end{document}
```

[image]